# if exist update or else insert in sqlite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I would like to implement this:

```
If exist
 update
Else 
 insert
```

It seems that I am touching the database two times. Is there any shorter way to implement this in sqlite3?

Comment: What about: `update`; if no rows were updated, then `insert`. Works best in an update-mostly scenario. Don't know how to implement in sqlite though.

Comment: @HansKesting - That's still two touches of the data for an insert, which the op is still trying to avoid.  I don't know SQLite3 so I don't know if it support MERGE or any other UPSERT type of syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a unique constraint on the key field, you could use the [`INSERT OR REPLACE` command](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) which automatically deletes the old record if the new one would create a duplicate.

However, this does not give you a performance advantage: There must *always* be *some* check for the record; whether you are doing an explicit `SELECT` or are using SQLite's built-in duplicate detection does not make much of a difference.